# the right options to traverse/download the pages/directories of a subdomain

Tags: bash, curl, download, wget

Let's suppose exist a site with the following directories (subdomain)

```
index.php
|-sub1
   |-index.php
   |-sub1sub1
     |-index.php
     |-other.php
     |-sub1sub1sub1
|-sub2
   |-index.php
   |- ….
|-sub3
   |- ...
```

My question is:

1. How can I display properly locally the site of the sub1 subdomain (http://domain/sub1)?
2. How can I get just the files and directory which are childs of sub1 (`sub1sub1` and `sub1sub1sub1` for example)?

I tried the following options (for wget) but it retrieves also the files and directories which are in `sub2`, `sub3` etc..

```
wget -E -H -k -K -r http://domain/sub1/index.php
```

Maybe should I write a few lines in bash?

Comment: no need for shell script ...

Answer (score 2):

To display the website-downloaded, you need to use the option `--convert-links` that redirect links to point to your local web pages.

To get only the 'child' files and not the parent, use `-np` that means `--no-parent`

how about using `-l depth` option that specify recursion maximum depth.

Here is the command you are looking for `wget  --mirror  --page-requisites -np --convert-links -P /Folder-local http://domain/sub1/index.php`

Answer (score 1):

`wget -r -np http://domain/sub1/`

you can use spider mode to get a listing first if you don't want everything in it

more detailed examples are here:

http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_mirror,_spider,_or_archive_a_website

Comment: `-R`means `--reject=LISTE` a reject a list of elements and does not answer the question.

Comment: it was supposed to be -r, granted the -r option works much better on ftp.